# What is the time complexity of below recursive functions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Below program is to find all the subsets of an array. Is time complexity of the program is O(2^n)?

Is there any easy way to find the time complexity of recursive function?

Thanks in anticipation

```
public static void getAllSubSet(int[] arr,int[] subset,int index){

        if(index == arr.length)
            printarr(subset);
        else{
            subset[index] = -1;
            getAllSubSet(arr, subset, index+1);
            subset[index] = arr[index];
            getAllSubSet(arr, subset, index+1);
        }

    }

    public static void printarr(int[] set){
        for(int i=0;i<set.length;i++){
            if(set[i] != -1){
                System.out.print(set[i] +" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int[] arr = {1,2,3};
        int[] subset = new int[arr.length];

        getAllSubSet(arr, subset, 0);


    }
```

Comment: It is not in `O(2^n)`. It is impossible to do better than `Θ(n2^n)` because that is the size of the output.

Comment: @Paulpro Yeah... my bad I forgot the print method... My main concern is about the recursive function. How to find the time complexity of recursive functions which are not dividing (like n-1 or n-2 in each recursive function) 
I know when function is dividing like n/2 or 3n/4 using masters method

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to your first question:**

The complexity of your function is `O(n* 2^n)`.  However if n is very large, you can neglect n.

**Answer to your second question:**

One of the best ways I find for approximating the complexity of the recursive algorithm is drawing the recursion tree. Once you have the recursive tree, you can find the complexity.